# Sticky nav on scroll acting weird in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I coded a simple, one-page website for my parents from scratch, and I added a simple navigation menu below the hero that sticks when it reaches the top of the browser on scroll. It works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox.

In Safari, the stick on scroll part works fine, but everything inside the navbar does this weird thing where it re-animates in from the left.

Here's the site: http://firstfruitsllc.com

Here's the little jQuery script and the CSS:

```
var mn = $(".nav");
mns = "nav-fixed";
hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```

```css
.nav {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-fixed {
  z-index: 999998;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.nav-fixed:before {
  z-index: 999999;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uezydedqpo55ub2/first-fruits-logo-color.svg?raw=1');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because new animatable properties are being added when the `.nav-fixed` class is added. Specifically `width` and `max-width`. To prevent this you can add

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 1440px;
```

to the `.nav` class.

Comment: Awesome, you guys were all correct. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like safari is having a hard time with the transition of no widths being declared to having both declared as it goes to fixed. Try this:

```
.nav
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Taking those lines from .nav-fixed and putting them in .nav did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `width: 100%` to `.navigation`, the glitch is gone. I cannot explain why Safari behaves so odd though.